# nested categories dropdown in magento

Tags: javascript, magento

I have the following working code in magento frontend in a form for customer "add a product" functionality that Im developing:

Helper area:

```
public function getCategoriesDropdown() {

    $categoriesArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
        ->load()
        ->toArray();


    foreach ($categoriesArray as $categoryId => $category) {
        if (isset($category['name'])) {
            $categories[] = array(
                'label' => $category['name'],
                'level'  =>$category['level'],
                'value' => $categoryId
            );
        }
    }
    return $categories;
}
```

PHTML File:

```
<select id="category-changer" name="category-changer" style="width:150px;">
        <option value="">--Select Categories--</option>
            <?php
             $_CategoryHelper = Mage::helper("marketplace")->getCategoriesDropdown();
                        foreach($_CategoryHelper as $value){
                            foreach($value as $key => $val){

                                if($key=='label'){
                                    $catNameIs = $val;
                                }
                                if($key=='value'){
                                    $catIdIs = $val;
                                }
                                if($key=='level'){
                                    $catLevelIs = $val;
                                    $b ='';
                                    for($i=1;$i<$catLevelIs;$i++){
                                        $b = $b."-";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $catIdIs; ?>"><?php echo $b.$catNameIs ?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

this code generates a dropdown with categories and subcategories. like this one:
[image]

my main idea is to create n level nested chained dropdowns for subcategories like this example:
[image]

or this layout would be better:
[image]

any guidance or code example to modify the proposed php in order to include an ajax call, or javascript to generate those frontend chained frontends will be appreciated

brgds!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my way:

In helper class, add method:

```
public function getCategoriesDropdown() {
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'));

    $first = array();
    $children = array();
    foreach ($categories->getItems() as $cat) {
        if ($cat->getLevel() == 2) {
            $first[$cat->getId()] = $cat;
        } else if ($cat->getParentId()) {
            $children[$cat->getParentId()][] = $cat->getData();
        }
    }

    return array('first' => $first, 'children' => $children);
}
```

In PHTML File:

```
<?php $tree = $this->helper('xxx')->getCategoriesDropdown(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var children = $H(<?php echo json_encode($tree['children']) ?>);

    function showCat(obj, level) {
        var catId = obj.value;
        level += 1;
        if ($('cat_container_' + level)) {
            $('cat_container_' + level).remove();
        }
        if (children.get(catId)) {
            var options = children.get(catId);
            var html = '<select id="cat_' + catId + '" onchange="showCat(this, ' + level + ')">';
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
            }
            html += '</select>';
            html = '<div id="cat_container_' + level + '">' + html + '</div>';

            $('sub_cat').insert(html);
        }
    }
</script>
<select id="first_cat" onchange="showCat(this, 2)">
    <?php foreach ($tree['first'] as $cat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat->getId() ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName() ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
<div id="sub_cat"></div>
```

Comment: hi @ndlinh it seems to work with 2 levels - onchange=showcat(this,2) -, do you know the way to create a N level nested dropdown?

Comment: sorry the delay. i read it but not tested. i will test. thks!

Comment: hi ndlinh your code is working fine but if i go for 3rd level and then again go for 1st level it will show previous second level in middle it will not removing 2nd level no matter if i select different parent one more thing i want to add submit button for all 3rd level as u can see if i add submit button it will work for only first level http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670243/i-add-a-search-button-on-select-change-but-its-working-only-for-one-level-magent

Answer (score 3):

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

/* You can play with this code */
echo '<select>';
echo getChildrenCategoryOptions($rootCategoryId);
echo '</select>';
/* You can play with this code */

function getChildrenCategoryOptions($categoryId) {
$html = '';
$_categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getChildrenCategories();

if( $_categoryCollection->count() > 0 ) {
    foreach($_categoryCollection as $_category) {

        $html .= '<option value="'.$_category->getId().'">'.str_repeat("-", ($_category->getLevel() - 2)).$_category->getName().'</option>';
        $html .= getChildrenCategoryOptions($_category->getId());
    }
    return $html;
}
else {
    return '';
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$categoriesHierachy = getChildrenCategoryOptions($rootCategoryId);


function getChildrenCategoryOptions($categoryId) {
$html = '';
$_categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getChildrenCategories();

if( $_categoryCollection->count() > 0 ) {
    foreach($_categoryCollection as $_category) {
        $array[$_category->getLevel()][$_category->getId()]['name'] = $_category->getName();
        $array[$_category->getLevel()][$_category->getId()]['subcategories'] = getChildrenCategoryOptions($_category->getId());
    }
    return $array;
}
else {
    return array();
}

}
```